# Changing all items of a viewmodel in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is a JS [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5861/) of a list in knockout JS. I would like to change all items in the list to this:

```
people: [
    {name:"Name1"},
    {name:"Name2"},
    {name:"Name3"}
    ]
```

But I have no idea since I dont know how to properly change the items of a viewModel in knockout JS.
In that particular example I also don't know where to add an event to the Change All button.
Here is an [example where I managed to](http://jsfiddle.net/aDahT/3028/) do it, but it is a little bit differrent and doesn't have all array items as observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap that into a JSON then assign it to a variable. And then use the same method `ko.mapping.fromJS` to reassign the new object:

```
....

var newPeople = 
{
  people: [
    {name:"Name1"},
    {name:"Name2"},
    {name:"Name3"}
]};

....

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

function changeAll() {
  ko.mapping.fromJS(newPeople, viewModel);
}
```